# Database storage

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I am new in iphone programming. I am making an application in which I want to enter the name, location  etc using iphone application and store it into database, so that I can retrieve any name any time or can store any user entry any time.

How can I implement this? Please give me some solution.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CoreData, a sqlite3 wrapper.

[iOS 4 CoreData tutorial](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Core_Data_Tutorial)

Comment: I have used the about link which you have refer me . I have made the same application by using the giving link. But whenever I save or find any name, the application get crash. I have checked it On console it is showing as below:                                   reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";                                       what does this mean..

Comment: Yeah that confused me too the first time, basically its because you changed the database model without removing the database, delete your app from your idevice/simulator and try again

Comment: you should  only get that error if you are using a database with a different layout than you specified in the xcdatamodel file. Can't help you much without seeing the code. I suggest looking at a xcode template, a navigation based iphone application can use CoreData, that might give you the information or code you need to get yours working too

Comment: yeah you can, jabwdr@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

As told by @Antwan van Houdt, You can go for CoreData or sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store only name and location use NSUserDefaults class instance as below.
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
use google for NSUserDefaults examples.